# SWRevealViewController is nil when add the gesture

Tags: ios

I am working on sidebar with storyboard. For this I have used `SWRevealViewController` Library.
In here in my Main Page at View did load event I have written

```
// Create left side navigation button
UIButton *btnMenu = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 20)];

[btnMenu setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_drawer2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnMenu addTarget:self.revealViewController action:@selector(revealToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// Set left side navigation button
UIBarButtonItem * menuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnMenu];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton;

// Set the gesture for nevigation drawer
[self.view addGestureRecognizer: self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

In the last line I am facing "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'" this error.

Comment: r u using in the bar button in VC, if yes y u create the button and istead into bar button , directly u added to bar button and add the swLRevalVC, would u need help to solve this is issue

Comment: There are no of problems related with SWReveal view controller in story board.... i am too struck with this problem thing before you use this library. this will create problems as i am suffereing now https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/issues/91

Comment: Try to add gesture in Button instead of [self.view]

Comment: I am not using bar button . that's why I am using here manual button. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: I have tried add gesture with Button instead of [self.view]. But still it is not working. May you please give me any other Solution? @XCodian